# How do I run a Python script from Java without hardcoded file path?

Tags: java, python, filepath, runtime.exec

Right now I have the absolute file path hardcoded into my Java program so that the Python script can be ran. However, when my program is deployed onto the company's platform, this file path will no longer be correct. The script is located in the same directory of the class which calls it, and this directory structure will not change. Is there a way to run the script just based on it being in the same directory?

Comment: Are you using `org.python.util.PythonInterpreter`?

Comment: why do you need absolute path? If it is on the class path, then there should be the way to call it with "./something/script" which would work where ever your app is brought to.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino scriptPath.exists() returns false for any relative path and only true for the absolute path.

Comment: And no I didn't use Jython

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to return the file path that the Java class was executed from:

```
final File path = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

You can then use this `path` object to load up the current directory and run your Python script.

Answer (score 1):

After trying what @Confiqure suggested, I found that the path was going one step too far into the directory structure of my program. Instead I tried:

```
String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath + "/my/path/to/script";
```

The `new File("").getAbsolutePath` returned the path to my application and from their I hardcoded the relative path, knowing that the path relative to my own application would never change.